# How to loaded ExtJS TreePanel from database table column2 as a ChildNode

Tags: oracle, jsp, extjs

**`My oracle database and getting Tree-panel :**  [image: Input data]

- Now I would like to display database table from column2 asa each
  Parent Node as Child Node please let me know how could I make it also
  my Json Data I am getting result like that please let me know how could I get child node ?

  My Expected result like :[image: result]

This is the JSON data :

```
[{
    "id":1,"reportTreeType":0,"text":"Root","reportType":null,"reportUrl":"", "hidden":false,
    "children":[{
        "id":5,"reportTreeType":0,"text":"Hardware","reportT‌​ype":"HardReport","reportUrl":"","hidden":false,"children":[], "leaf":false,"dirName":"","href":"","reportId":0,"qtip":""}]
```

I have tried ExtJS Tree-Panel below like but I am getting from table-1 column1 parent node not getting column2 child nodes ?

```
Ext
.onReady(function() {
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel(
            {id : 'treePanel',
                el : 'tree-div',
                useArrows : true,
                title : 'Export',
                autoScroll : true,
                width : 250,
                region : 'west',
                animate : true,
                enableDD : true,
                containerScroll : true,
                enableKeyEvents : true,
                collapsible : true,
                split : true,
                rootVisible : false,
                border : false,
                // auto create TreeLoader
                dataUrl :'<c:url value="/customize/ExportReport.do?method=getExport"/>',
                root : {
                    nodeType : 'async',
                    text : 'Root',
                    draggable : false,
                    id : '-1',
                    expanded:true,


               //here Children node I cannot able to rendered where I have made mistake ? 
                   children:[{
            text: reportT‌​ype, //TreeNode Java class variable 
            leaf: true }]
        }
                } }); });
```

Comment: Above expected result having two columns first column as a Parent nodes and 2nd column as a child node i need to display child node for each parent node?

Comment: Sorry, but nothing is clear. What do you get now and what do you want to get? What are those red lines in the picture? What JSON do you have now and why isn't it good?

Comment: Sorry for that ,I have json data which is text as a parent node  and name as child node is it possible to split this dynamic json data to display tree panel ? **[{"id":1,"reportTreeType":0,"text":"Root","reportType":null,"reportUrl":"",
"hidden":false,"children":[{"id":5,"reportTreeType":0,"text":"Hardware","reportType":"HardReport","reportUrl":"","hidden":false,"children":[],
"leaf":false,"dirName":"","href":"","reportId":0,"qtip":""}]**

Comment: **I Mean above json data can I have split it parent node as a Root , Hardware ,child node as a HardReport ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you would like that `Hardware` is a child of `Root` and `HardReport` a child of `Hardware`.

I think there is no direct solution in ExtJs.

- you change your backend to send the correct data
- you have to manually parse the JSON
- you load the data in a first tree store, and then you build a second tree store by looping through the first.

Comment: Yes your right I expected like that , could you please let me know how could I do it ? Can I have change my database table column2  data insert into column1 ? I have tried  query **INSERT INTO table1
(column1)SELECT column2 FROM table1;** still I am getting cannot able to insert null values ?Is it I am in correct track ?

Comment: I am using server side  Spring MVC ,ExtJS4.0 with oracle databse , so from database loaded dynamically without using ExtJS data store , could you please let me know how could I build a second tree store by looping of the first tree ?

Comment: Example :'If(entity.getReportType().equals("ROOT") || entity.getReportType().equals("HARDWARE"){List<Entity> listArray = new ArrayList<Entity>(); List<Child> list = serviceClass.getReport(entity.getId);for(Export export:list){listArray .add(list); } }' **please let me know how could I add child loop through first node ? **

Comment: Do you really have no way to change the format of the data that is returned? Change the format of the JSON is certainly the easiest solution.

Comment: Also I don't understand the requirement. Is this only a display issue? If yes, probably a tree grid instead of a simple tree would be the best solution. If on the other hand the hardware can have more than one report, certainly the way the data is returned is not appropriate and you should modify the backend.

Comment: Either way, it is easier to stick to the behavior of ExtJs, rather than force it to behave against nature.

Comment: Thanks for reply me .could you please let me know sample Json data format to achieve my result . Because I am newbie for EXTJs ?

Comment: Please answer my questions first.

Comment: I have refer  this [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691194/how-to-change-json-format-for-load-data-to-highchart) but not get clear I have my code like `JSONArray JsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(tvlist);`

Comment: Yes only display issue ? simple Tree ? how could it ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is far from clear enough. I fear I'm not able to help you further, without your answer.

Comment: I am using Treepanel hierarchy is any good solution future If I have added more rows in column2 data cannot give error ?

Comment: Hi Lorenz Meyer please look my post I have added my TreePanel , but still I am not able to show 2nd column as a child node If any database changes needed ?

Comment: The second column cannot be a child. Either you make it a child in the JSON data or you display it as a second column.

Comment: You mean ?I want to declare like that List<TreeNode> Child=null ;//getter and setter method ? here JSON data text:'Root' ,name:'HardwareType' ? how can I display both in Tree-Panel ?

Comment: please look at my post I have added few more code but still I cannot rendered child node .where I have made mistaken ?